# Docker compose not building while docker build not having any problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a RESTful API build with Express and NodeJS which I would like to package into a Docker Image. The Image builds without any Problem when using the following command:

```
docker build . -t api
```

but when using docker-compose to build it using this command:

```
docker-compose build
```

I get this Error:

```
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: target stage production could not be found
```

This is my Docker-file:

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS backend

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app/backend

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

And this is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: lvd-voucher-backend
    image: lvd-voucher-backend
    build:
      context: .
      target: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

I'm pretty new to docker so I hope you can help me :D

Comment: The `target: name` line needs to match one of the `FROM ... AS name` stages in the Dockerfile.  It's not usually needed and will default to the last stage (or, in your case, the only stage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why under `services.backend.build` is `target` set?    Your docker file is not a multi stage build.  I recommend you remove that line.   https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/build.md#target